# Query on concept of a record in Oracle Berkeley DB

Tags: c, database, berkeley-db

As per the [link](https://www.stanford.edu/class/cs276a/projects/docs/berkeleydb/ref/intro/dbisnot.html), I have learnt that record is `(key,value)` in berkeley DB, In contrast with record being a `tuple`(one row in a table) in relational model database.

But when i run an example application(`display.exe`) that uses Oracle berkeley DB  C API, i get the following table information

```
$ display

table1
table2
table3
table4
```

With below commaond, I get rows of `table1`

```
$ display table1
```

[image]

From the above table, I understand that, any app that  uses berk DB API can put/get data and actually store internally  in the form of `(key,value)` like `(Colname1,0x300003) (Colname2, World) (Colname3, 0x10040) (Colname4, World) (Colname1, 0x30004a) (Colname2, 'EnterpriseVPN M')...` But, we see this data in the form of tables because `display` module is fetching the (key,value) pairs internally and presenting it as table rows.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: if yes, can we also think of object model or relational model database as a wrapper over berkeley DB?

Answer (score 1):

Not quite correct.  In your example, the key is not obvious.  Each "table" is probably a database.  The "value" would be a C structure with four fields: Colname1, Colname2, Colname3, and Colname4.  Not totally in contrast to a relational DB.  Here, a record is still one row.

However, you must choose one of those fields to be the key -- you'd have to decide how you want the data indexed.  Though BDB is capable of dealing with duplicate keys, you may find it problematic to use it in practice.  So, your key should be unique.

For example, perhaps the data in Colname1 are the keys?  If so, you could do a db->get(0x300039) and retrieve the record with 0x300039, MgmtInventory, 0x25e0000, and MgmtInventory.

Comment: i just saw the code, yes, each table is a database. so in a database you can just only insert (key,value) pair? nothing more than that?yes, we are creating 4 databases for 4 tables. and is that the reason that the code is generating the these hex numbers to keep it as key? so the (key, value) scenario for first row is something like (0x300003,(0x300003,"World",0x10040,"World")) , am i correct?

Comment: coming from relational model database(MSSQL) background, this looks weird to me that we need to create a database per table. so Can't we think of relations between database(table) like 'primary-foreign key relation' or write stored procedure/trigger for a table or views for a table or index for a table?

Comment: You don't necessarily need to create multiple databases.  One common technique is to include the table type as part of the key.  Your key could be (table1, 0x300003), for example.  And, regarding your other comment, yes, you insert key/value pairs.  Of course, you can insert many, many of these into one database.  I have no idea why the code would be using those numbers for a key.  You can use anything you'd like for a key!  A string, a whole structure, whatever... as long as it's unique.